# MVC Refresh View with dropzone and sweet alert

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sweetalert

There are some really nice packages out to make the look and feel of website kinda cool.  Dropzone and Sweet alert are two that I am utilizing (trying to) for my project.  I have a simple view that displays the dropzone on the 1st half of the screen and displays the "grid" on the bottom half.  When files are uploaded, I do a refresh in the view to show the new grid contents. This works great in my view:

```
this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
    alert("All files have uploaded ");
    location.reload();
});
```

notice I am using the standard alert.  By working great, I mean that the alert comes up after the upload, the when I click OK, the screen refreshes.  I though i would just replace the alert with the sweet alert:

```
this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
    swal({ title: 'File(s) uploaded successfully!', type: 'info',  confirmButtonText: 'OK' });
    location.reload();   
});
```

The sweet alert flashes for a second and the page is reloaded.  I tried all kinds of things before posting this.  Is this just a defect in sweet alert?  How can I get it to what for my click before executing the reload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
swal({
    title: "File(s) uploaded successfully!",
    type: "info",
    timer: 3000,
    confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    });
    function () {
       location.reload();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see what you were trying to do! Format was a little off:

```
                     swal({
                        title: "File(s) uploaded successfully!",
                        type: "info",
                        timer: 30000000,
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                    },
                    function X() {
                        //alert("All files have uploaded ");
                        location.reload();
                    });
```

WORKS GREAT!!